# TSQL, break period by Month only for given year

Tags: t-sql, time-series, period

I'm trying to break membership periods by month, but only for given year, in our example it ***2022***
Self inclusive code below works fine but it breaks all period, I only trying to process by month for 2022.  Code below also holds definition for test data inside (`#t temp table`). I'm using #numbers table as a tally.  I'm using SQL Server 2017

```
/*  
SELECT TOP 100  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n     
INTO #numbers     FROM   master.dbo.spt_values  --- Select top 100 * from #t numbers
  -----    data prep part
SELECT * INTO #t  FROM (    --   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  #t
          SELECT 100 ID,  CAST('2022-03-02' AS DATE) eStart ,  CAST('2022-03-15' AS DATE) eEnd, '1 Same Month island' note , 100 Idx
    UNION SELECT 200,  '2022-01-11' ,   '2022-03-27', '2 Same Month Start 1', 2001
    UNION SELECT 200,  '2022-02-15' ,   '2022-5-15', '2 Same Month Start 2', 2002
    UNION SELECT 300,  '2021-05-08' ,   '2024-12-31', '3 Future eEnd ' ,3000
    UNION SELECT 440,  '2022-10-15' ,   '2023-10-10', '4 Future end 2' ,4400 
) b      --    SELECT * FROM #t
*/

select DISTINCT t.ID,
  CASE WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)) < 2022 THEN eStart
       WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)) > 2022 THEN '1/1/2023'  -- first day after 2022  
       ELSE  CASE WHEN n = 0  then t.eStart   ELSE   dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)   END 
                                                                          END  eStart,  
  case when n = datediff(month, eStart, eEnd)   then t.eEnd
       else eomonth(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0))  END eEnd 
    --   ,n, note ,eStart eStartOrig, eEnd eEndOrig
from   #t t
join #numbers n on n.n <= datediff(month, eStart, eEnd)
order by t.ID, eStart
```

[image]

Comment: You might find it easier to handle all of the data `< '20220101'` `union all` with the data for `>= '20230101'` `union all` the months `>= '20220101' and` `< '20230101'`. Tip: The [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag description has a handy reference for determining whether two ranges overlap or not.

Comment: After posting a proposed answer below, I noticed a few discrepancies in the above-posted desired output. (1) Should the third row have an `eStart` date of `2/15/2022` or should it be `2/1/2022`? (2) For the second and third 440 rows, shouldn't the `eEnd` dates be 2022 dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggested approach would be to build a "months" table for the desired range, join with your membership data, and keep pairs with overlapping date ranges. From there you can adjust the start and end dates to be the more restrictive between the actual mempership period and the selected month.

When comparing date ranges for overlap, a standard comparison is `Start1 < End2 AND Start2 < End1` when dealing with exclusive end-dates or date/times. When dealing with inclusive end dates (as is the case here), the comparison becomes `Start1 <= End2 AND Start2 <= End1`

The resulting logic would then be something like:

```
-- Membership data #t as defined in original post

SELECT
    A.MonthStart,
    EOMONTH(A.MonthStart) AS MonthEnd
INTO #months
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) N(N)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2022, N.N, 1) AS MonthStart) A

SELECT * from #months

SELECT
    t.ID,
    CASE WHEN m.MonthStart >= t.eStart THEN m.MonthStart ELSE t.eStart END AS eStart,
    CASE WHEN m.MonthEnd <= t.eEnd THEN m.MonthEnd ELSE t.eEnd END AS eEnd,
    t.Idx
FROM #t t
JOIN #months m -- Overlapping months (inclusive dates)
    ON m.MonthStart <= t.eEnd 
    AND t.eStart <= m.MonthEnd 
ORDER BY t.ID, t.Idx, eStart -- Added t.Idx to better match desired results
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zUu8kJWz) for a demo.

If you want to include prior and following membership date ranges, you can include extra rows in the #months table such as:

- 1900-01-01 to 2021-12-31
- 2023-01-01 to 12-31-9999

or specific full-year ranges if that is what is wanted.

Comment: Thanks TN, my output is correct, for duplicate I want to split period no matter if intersect exists or not, I also noticed that it doesn't work correct for ID=440. There is no period prior 2022. But it's OK, I come with DISTINCT and Case which worked OK

Comment: Correction to my comment, <doesn't work correctly for ID = 300>. I posted by solution below which works OK

Comment: @MarioTrento Adding beginning-of-time and end-of-time ranges to the months table using`INSERT #months VALUES ('1900-01-01', '2021-12-31'), ('2023-01-01', '2099-12-31')` will include the outside-of-2022 ranges in your result. (I mistakenly had the wrong year numbers in my earlier post.) Personally, if I were a developer coming in after you to maintain this code, I think I would prefer the version with a few less case statements.

Comment: Updated db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jpxKCVYd).

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT t.ID,
  CASE WHEN 
      YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)) < 2022 
         THEN eStart
      WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)) > 2022 
         THEN '1/1/2023'  -- first day after 2022  
      ELSE  
         CASE WHEN n = 0  
             then t.eStart   
         ELSE   dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0)   
         END 
      END  eStart,  
     CASE WHEN YEAR(         
          CASE WHEN n = DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.eStart, t.eEnd)  THEN t.eEnd  ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0))    END) < 2022
              THEN CASE 
                      WHEN t.eEnd < '1/1/2022'  
                      THEN t.eEnd  
                      ELSE DATEADD(d,-1,'1/1/2022') 
                   END
          WHEN YEAR(
              CASE WHEN 
                 n = DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.eStart, t.eEnd)  THEN t.eEnd  ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0))    
              END   ) > 2022
              THEN t.eEnd
          ELSE
              CASE WHEN 
                 n = DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.eStart, t.eEnd)  
                 THEN t.eEnd  
                 ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.eStart) + n, 0))    
              END        
     END                                     eEnd  

from   #t t
join #numbers n on n.n <= datediff(month, eStart, eEnd)
```